# Issues with custodial and non custodial wallet smart contract interactions

Tags: go-ethereum, gas-price, gas-limit

We have smart contract for minting ERC721 tokens. The non custodial mints work fine through Javascript but custodial mints are always in pending state. We are using `go-ethereum` to make that smart contract calls.

Here are the transactions for [custodial](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xe57e9ebb66b6091fb979a65bbcb572fd34b2babfd3b03ce49cc38e13e244c824) and [non custodial](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xaa4e722a4ee8cb78cdc35a1d2b5e7fc7beb143300254cf6c5eb4c0e3f7ee9395) mints respectively.

Can someone suggest why these transactions are at different states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because, a transaction from our wallet was in pending state due to low gas fee.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is simple.

Firstly it has nothing to Do with Custodial or Non-Custodial Wallets.

This issue has been caused due to the Gas Price, Gas Fees and the Gas Limit

As we can see Clearly In Etherscan

```
  This txn hash was found in our secondary node and should be picked up by our indexer in a short while.
```

The Issue Can be Resolved by setting the Gas Price, Gas Limit High